# Voice Live Streaming in Agora.io

Tags: agora.io

We need to implement a Clubhouse-like feature in our mobile app, where users will be able to have voice-only chat rooms. In a room, there will be approximately 10 broadcasters and hundreds of listeners.

I found the Agora.io service and I started testing their APIs. I see that they have the `Voice Call` (AgoraAudio_iOS SDK) and the `Live Interactive Streaming` (AgoraRtcEngine_iOS SDK). I am confused as to how they differ. What differences do they have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Voice Call SDK is a subset of the Live Interactive streaming.  The voice call SDK only has the audio support part of its superset.  The Live Interactive Streaming (a.k.a the video sdk) has video related functionalities.